# EJB 3.0 and SQL

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jdeveloper

I am trying to build a simple application with JDeveloper 11g. I connect to a MSSQL Server 2008 database and get data from it. 
I am new at Enterprise Java Beans 3.0 so I don't know what code I should write for data update, delete or insert and where to write. I made an application(Fusion Web Application) but the changes I made on that application don't affect the database.I am new at Enterprise Java Beans 3.0 so I don't know what code I should write for data update, delete or insert and where to write. Could anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have several options, but the recommended way* is to use JPA (Java Persistence API) for storage and retrieval of your data. To learn JPA, you can read this chapter of Java EE tutorial: [Introduction to the Java Persistence API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html)

*: For some projects it makes sense to consider other options as well, but JPA is the standard persistence technology of Java EE 5 and 6.

Comment: Agreed.  Sometimes raw SQL is the way to go for legacy apps.  Sometimes other options are the right way.  However, starting fresh and not having any particular special requirements, I'd choose JPA because it's "built-in".